# Suitescript 2.0 - How to show a field and update value based on dropdown?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

I have a drop down that, when a particular option is selected a hidden field will be displayed and that field which have a new value. I am able to get the field to display but am not able to populate the field with the value. Script below:

```
           function fieldChanged(context) {
                var records = context.currentRecord;
                if (context.fieldId == 'custbody_data') {
                    var note = context.currentRecord.getField({ fieldId: 'custbody_note' });

                    var type = records.getValue({
                        fieldId: 'custbody_data'
                    });

                    if (type == "2") {
                        note.isDisplay = true;
                        note.setValue = "test";

                    } else if (type == "1") {
                       note.isDisplay = false;
                       note.setValue = "";
                    }
                }
            }

return {
fieldChanged: fieldChanged
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> `note.setValue = "";`

There are two problems in what you are trying to do:

1. With the NetSuite API, to manipulate the value of fields in the record you need to use the `N/currentRecord#Record` object , not the `N/currentRecord#Field`. In other words you need to be calling `context.currentRecord.setValue()`.
2. `setValue` is a [method, not a property](https://teamtreehouse.com/community/difference-between-object-methods-and-object-properies). I.e.  you need to call the function `setValue()` with the new value, and not assign it a value (`note.setValue = "new value"`) like you are attempting.

Putting those together, the correct syntax for updating a field value is:

```
context.currentRecord.setValue({
  fieldId: 'custbody_note',
  value: "test",
});
```